# How to load appsettings directly from Memory cache

Tags: iis, caching, memory, appsettings

I want to load appsettings from app.config or web.config,
without using the Configuration manager or configuration settings.

Instead I want it to use from Memory cache directly.

Since memory cache holds the current running project app data :
Is there a way to load it directly from it?

Comment: appsettings will be cached only when you retrieve data for the first time. So I think you can't access memory cache from the beginning.
Configurationmanager will read appsetting from memory cache automatically. Is there any concern to use it in your application?

Comment: No, my application is working properly. I just wanted to know how the configuration manager works. I know that we can cache the appsettings data after fetching using the configuration manager till the application run, but how configuration manager works? Is it using xml logic internally or some other way to retrieve those data and save in the Dictionary Format

Comment: It just use getsection("appsetting") internally.You could review part code logic here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs,82b0d78ddc6f04b3